Make adding custom instrumentation in Sentry less verbose
I'm playing around with instrumentation using Sentry and I'm so discouraged by how many lines of code I have to add everywhere.
According to the Sentry docs, I have to add all these lines every time I want to measure something:
        $sentryTransactionContext = (new TransactionContext('Something that needs measuring'));
        $sentryTransactionContext->setOp('http.server');
        $sentryTransaction = startTransaction($sentryTransactionContext);
        SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($sentryTransaction);
        $spanContext = (new SpanContext());
        $spanContext->setOp('something.that.needs.measuring');
        $span1 = $sentryTransaction->startChild($spanContext);
        \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($span1);

        // Do something that needs to be measured...

        $span1->finish();
        SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($sentryTransaction);
        $sentryTransaction->finish();

Is all that stuff really supposed to go in all my different Controller methods, or places where I need to measure how long a piece of code takes? It would be so much duplicate code.
Ideally, I would like to just do this:
public function create(HttpRequest $request)
{
        sentry_measure_start('slow.task');

        // Something slow that needs to be measured

        sentry_measure_stop('slow.task');
}

Is that possible?

You could write a Service class that handles and simplifies the syntax for starting and stopping Sentry transactions and spans.

Create a app/Services/SentryMeasureService.php
namespace App\Services;

use Sentry\Tracing\TransactionContext;
use Sentry\Tracing\SpanContext;
use Sentry\SentrySdk;

class SentryMeasure {
    private static $transactions = [];
    private static $spans = [];

    /**
     * Start measuring a transaction or span
     * 
     * @param string $name Unique identifier for the transaction or span
     * @param string $type Type of measurement (transaction or span)
     * @param string|null $parentName Parent transaction/span name (optional)
     */
    public static function start(string $name, string $type = 'transaction', ?string $parentName = null)
    {
        try {
            if ($type === 'transaction') {
                // Create and start a new transaction
                $transactionContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\TransactionContext($name);
                $transactionContext->setOp('http.server');
                $transaction = \Sentry\startTransaction($transactionContext);

                \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($transaction);

                self::$transactions[$name] = $transaction;
            } elseif ($type === 'span') {
                if (!isset(self::$transactions[$parentName])) {
                    throw new \Exception("Parent transaction '{$parentName}' not found");
                }

                $parentTransaction = self::$transactions[$parentName];

                $spanContext = new \Sentry\Tracing\SpanContext();
                $spanContext->setOp($name);
                $span = $parentTransaction->startChild($spanContext);

                \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($span);

                self::$spans[$name] = $span;
            } else {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid measurement type. Use 'transaction' or 'span'.");
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log("Sentry measurement start error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop measuring a transaction or span
     * 
     * @param string $name Unique identifier for the transaction or span to stop
     * @param string $type Type of measurement (transaction or span)
     */
    public static function stop(string $name, string $type = 'transaction')
    {
        try {
            if ($type === 'transaction') {
                if (isset(self::$transactions[$name])) {
                    $transaction = self::$transactions[$name];
                    $transaction->finish();

                    unset(self::$transactions[$name]);
                }
            } elseif ($type === 'span') {
                if (isset(self::$spans[$name])) {
                    $span = self::$spans[$name];
                    $span->finish();

                    unset(self::$spans[$name]);

                    if (!empty(self::$transactions)) {
                        $lastTransactionName = array_key_last(self::$transactions);
                        $lastTransaction = self::$transactions[$lastTransactionName];
                        \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($lastTransaction);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid measurement type. Use 'transaction' or 'span'.");
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log("Sentry measurement stop error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}


Create a app/helpers.php file to implement your helper functions
use App\Services\SentryMeasureService;

if (!function_exists('sentry_measure_start')) {
    function sentry_measure_start(string $name, ?string $parentName = null)
    {
        SentryMeasureService::start($name, $parentName === null ? 'transaction' : 'span', $parentName);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('sentry_measure_stop')) {
    function sentry_measure_stop(string $name)
    {
        SentryMeasureService::stop($name, 'span');
        SentryMeasureService::stop($name, 'transaction');
    }
}


To make the helper functions visible you need to modify your composer.json more specifically the autoload key. Add a files array
inside autoload.
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},


Once you added the file you need to dump the autloader
composer dump-autoload



Now you should be able to use the functions the way you suggested:
public function create(Request $request)
{
    sentry_measure_start('slow.task');

    sleep(2); // example of a slow operation

    sentry_measure_stop('slow.task');
}


I found that Sentry's SDK has a less verbose static method that apparently isn't mentioned in the documentation. Here's how I use it. It's still a little cumbersome, but tolerable.
        $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getTransaction()
            ?: startTransaction(TransactionContext::make()->setName('slow.task')->setOp('slow.task1'));
        $child = $transaction->startChild(SpanContext::make()->setOp('slow.task1.subtask1'));

        // measure something

        $child->finish();
        $transaction->finish();

